# Can't change flutter existing project to flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
flutter create .
```

It created well but it can't run.

```
flutter run -d chrome

Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
/C:/studio%20sdk/flutternew/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-1.3.0/lib/src/extended_image.dart:785:44: Error: No named parameter with the
```

name 'nullOk'.
_invertColors = MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)?.invertColors ??
^^^^^^
/C:/studio%20sdk/flutternew/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:818:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
^^
Waiting for connection from debugging service on Chrome...             24.5s
Failed to compile the application.

Comment: Provide more information. In the first place ensure that everyone is on the same page instead of just posting code. Approach people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case Alienspaces answer doesn't help, this might be an error with the `extended_image` package. Maybe it doesn't support web yet?

You can try to temporarily fix the error the following way:

1. Go into the file with the error (C:/studio%20sdk/flutternew/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/extended_image-1.3.0/lib/src/extended_image.dart)
2. Go to line 785
3. replace `MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)` with `MediaQuery.of(context)`

Comment: after this change blank chrome tab opened

Comment: Sounds like you were able to fix the main problem and get it running.
You have to provide your main.dart or initial screen so I can help you getting it to actually display your widgets.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As noted in the comment Flutter web is now on stable, as such there is no longer any need to switch to the `beta` channel!

From the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) you might want to try:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter create .
```

Comment: Btw, Flutter Web is on stable now, so the first command isn't necessary anymore :)